# Внедрение php в c++ проект

Tags: php, c++

Есть необходимость использовать php - интерпретатор для обработки php страниц с php-кодом в Qt C++ проекте. Запускаю php.exe, пишу туда текст, получаю вывод. Это работает, но довольно медленно. На обработку ~300 страниц уходит 30 секунд. Нет ли библиотек для подключения к своему проекту, чтоб обработка происходила по вызову функции, а не запуска внешнего приложения?

Comment: Параллелить пробовали?

Comment: Это конечно ускорит работу, правда и усложнит логику. Но хотелось бы сразу узнать, возможно есть более "правильный" способ?

Comment: Правильно - не использовать php, но я думаю, что Вам это не нравится. Поэтому, можно использовать dll с php вместо запуска exe файла. Это немного сэкономит время.

Comment: Если есть возможность использовать Visual Studio 2015, то там есть плагин, не помню как называется, вроде php tool.

Comment: @Duracell на сколько я понял - php tool - это плагин, для автодополнений, подсветки синтаксиса и возможности отладки. Это совсем не то что мне нужно.

Comment: @Александр - значит я ошибся в названии плагина, давно дело имел с совмещением с++ и пхп

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте [FastCGI](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/FastCGI) совместно с [php-fpm](http://php.net/manual/ru/install.fpm.php). Подобно как работают с PHP [nginx](http://adw0rd.com/2010/1/27/nginx-and-php-fpm/) и прочите сервера с поддержкой FastCGI.

Comment: nginx не как не работает с php он тупо проксирует, то есть отправляет запрос на `php-fpm` или какой либо другой интерпритатор, и получает ответ в виде некой html (в довольно грубом представление), страницы которую и отдаёт в порт своего http сервера(сформировав заголовки, тела и футеры). Так что ввы правы и в этом случае можно просто запрашивать и получать. Но можно и держать сервер, который будет формировать инфу а прога сохранять эти данные в cache, с возможностью переодичного обновления cache.

Comment: > nginx не как не работает с php -
вопрос терминологии. Напрямую - нет (в  отличии от LUA, к примеру, или Perl (с perl-module)). Но используя протокол FastCGI - да. Собственно я про то и написал.